# Как написать JOIN?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить следующую задачу.
Я хочу отобразить список всех пользователей, при этом напротив тех пользователей на которых подписан текущий пользователь системы, я буду отрисовывать сердечко.

У меня имеется 2 таблицы (users, followers), а так же id текущего пользователся. Результирующая таблица должна содержать ровно столько строк сколько пользователей в системе (за исключением текущего, то есть на одну строку меньше), при этом в строках пользователей, на которых подписан текущий должна присутствовать какая-то отметка об этом.

Вот скрины таблиц для примера
users [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

followers (follower - это id юзера, а following - id юзера на которого подписан follower)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста предложите варианты решения данной задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приблизительно так (при f.id не null ставить сердечко):

```
select u.id, u.name, f.id
from users u left join followers f on u.id = f.following and f.follower = @id
where u.id <> @id
```

Возможно, можно как-то оптимизировать.

Comment: Индексы добавить можно, что-то аля `alter table users add index users_idx_id (id)` (ну и фолловерам тоже можно), ну и left join заменить на inner join - вот и вся "оптимизация"

Comment: @InDevX, с inner работать не будет - вопрос посмотри. Я под оптимизацией имел в виду загнать `f.follower = @id` куда-то внутрь join.

Comment: @Akina, написано, что текущего не надо: _"ровно столько строк сколько пользователей в системе (за исключением текущего, то есть на одну строку меньше)"_. Условие я подвинул, просто не был уверен, что так можно.

Comment: Да, это я проглядел, сорри. *не был уверен, что так можно* Во-первых, можно. Во-вторых - нужно, иначе LEFT JOIN быстренько превращается в INNER JOIN, и результат далёк от ожидаемого.

Comment: @Akina, что значит превращается в inner?

Comment: Ты выполнил LEFT JOIN. Что он делает? Сперва сервер составляет все пары (левая-правая), для которых выполняется условие связывания, фактически выполняя INNER JOIN, потом добавляет к ним пары (левая-null) для тех из левой, которым не нашлось пары. А ты потом накладываешь WHERE по правой. При этом ни одна суммарная запись из группы (левая-null) эту проверку не пройдёт (null почему-то ничему не равен), и все они будут отброшены. И останутся только записи, соответствующие INNER JOIN связыванию (часть из коих также может быть отсеяна условием WHERE).

Comment: @Akina, понял - я об этом не подумал... Теперь правильно?

Comment: Не совсем пойму что значат буквы 'u' перед left и 'f' после followers. Я пользовался вот таким запросом. `SELECT users.name, users.id, followers.follower, followers.following FROM users LEFT JOIN followers ON users.id = followers.following WHERE users.id != $1` (где вместо $1 подставлялся текущий, например 6й). Но это привело к дублированию строк.

Comment: Я отредактировал таблицу followers. Вот результат запроса
[ { name: 'Michael', id: 5, follower: 4, following: 5 },
  { name: ' Yuri', id: 2, follower: 6, following: 2 },
  { name: 'Tatiana', id: 3, follower: 6, following: 3 },
  { name: 'Michael', id: 5, follower: 6, following: 5 },
  { name: 'Alex', id: 4, follower: null, following: null } ]

Comment: получаю строку с "Michael" 2 раза, причем на одного я подписан, а на другого нет.

Comment: @Nikitich, ты используешь не тот запрос, который я написал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Спасибо, это работает.